# how to refer to id in jsf by its part from two levels down in of its sibling

Tags: jsf

Colleagues,

How in JSF can I refer to element by its id from grandson of its sibling:

```html
<h:panelGrid id="designFileLoad">

    <h:panelGrid id="panelGridOne">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuOne">
            <f:ajax event="change" execute=":designFileLoad:panelGridTwo" render=":designFileLoad:panelGridTwo"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid id="panelGridTwo">
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:panelGrid>
```

When I refer it by :designFileLoad:panelGridTwo in attributes execute and render of f:ajax it does not work and log says that it is impossble to find an element with such id inside the context of an element selectOneMenuOne. I have Mojarra 2.1.29 so @parent is not available.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `execute/render="panelGridTwo"`. Those components are NOT naming containers. See also abovelinked duplicate.